# Is there any standard name for Provably Decidable Set?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

A function $f:\mathbb{N}^k\to\mathbb{N}$ is **Provably Total** in Arithmetical recursively enumerable Theory $T$ if there exists a $\Sigma_1$ formula $\phi({\bf x},y)$ in language of $T$ such that:

1. $T\vdash \forall {\bf x}\exists!y\phi({\bf x},y)$
2. $\mathbb{N}\models \forall{\bf x}\phi({\bf x},f({\bf x}))$.

(Suppose $\mathbb{N}\models T$.)

> Def. A set $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is **Provably Decidable** in
>   Arithmetical recursively enumerable Theory $T$ if $\chi_{\mathcal{A}}$ is provably total in
>   $T$.

Is there any standard name or reference for Provably Decidable sets of Theory $T$?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you intend to assume that $T$ is computably enumerable? Or that $T$ is true in the standard model? Or that $T$ contains some specific weak theory?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: I edited my post. about your third question, Is there any difference for definition of provably decidable set if for example $I\Delta_0\subseteq T$ ?

Comment: What does "arithmetical" mean here? (Since $T$ is recursively enumerable, it's certainly arithmetical in the computability-theoretic sense . . .)

Comment: @NoahSchweber:I mean $T$ is in language of arithmetic($\mathcal{L}_T=\{0,S,+,\cdot\}$)

Comment: For all levels of the arithmetical hierarchy ($\Sigma_n$, $\Pi_n$, $\Delta_n$), a definable set $A$ my be (for example) "$\Sigma_n$ in the standard model of arithetic" or "provabily $\Sigma_n$ in $T$). Obviously the later implies the former (if $T$ is sound) but the converse is not necessarily true. So I think another name for your concept is "provabily (in $T$) $\Delta_1$".

Comment: @PayamSeraji: Interesting comment. Thank you.

Comment: You are wellcome.